# How to plot tweets by location in real time on to a map e.g. leaflet

Tags: python, twitter, gis, flask, leaflet

I would like to know what would be the best way to plot real-time tweets by their location onto a map application such as leaflet.

At the moment I am getting the tweets by the streaming api(filtered) and storing into a mongodb. I would like to know how I can best achieve this. I'm using python and the flask framework.

So a tweet's information is stored into a DB and plotted in real-time onto the map concurrently.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Seems like you would want to use GeoJSON for this: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/geojson.html

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried anything yet. If I have tweet information stored in a mongoDB, then would I need select all objects with geo information and then store them as GeoJson first?                                                              Would there be no way to read directly from the db as a client query is received and then select objects to plot in real time as tweets are stored?

Comment: You need to get the data out of Mongo, convert to GeoJSON format, and provide this data to Leaflet.  Since Leaflet is running in a browser you should get the data from your server via HTTP which means that you  need to run a webserver that can access your mongo database.  I don't have experience with any but looks like there are some HTTP frontends for Mongo: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that.

Comment: I would also look at a more client side reactive platform on the client side, such as Meteor there is a great example at https://github.com/bevanhunt/meteor-leaflet-demo

Comment: +1 for the meteor example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This repo shows how to use Flask and Mongo with Leaflet

https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-mongo-flask-example

If you can either write a timer loop in your JS page to do an Ajax request at a regular interval or you will need something like WebSockets on the server and the client